# Uncaught TypeError: d.Wa is not a function

Tags: openlayers, geojson, vector, layers, features

I am trying to add a feature collection fetched from a server to the source of an empty vector layer, but I am getting this error (using OpenLayers 3):

Uncaught TypeError: d.Wa is not a function

I am not finding much online to describe this error.  IT is thrown at this point in my code:

segment.getSource().addFeatures(features);

the segment layer is initialized globally, with an empty source (I am using Backbone)

```
 window.globals.segment = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({

            }),
      visible: true,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#022835',
              width: 4
          })
      })
  });
```

The features are fetched from a server then read into a geojson:

```
            if (response.length > 0) {

                   if (response[0][0].features[0].geometry.type === 'MultiLineString') {

                       _.map(respfeatures.features, function (feature) {
                        feature.properties.segmentid = feature.properties.f1;
                        feature.properties.street = feature.properties.f2;
                    });
                } else {
                       _.map(respfeatures.features, function (feature) {
                        feature.properties.nodeid = feature.properties.f1;
                    });
                }


                   return new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(respfeatures.features, {
                    dataProjection: 'EPSG:2263',
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', rightHanded; false
                   });

            }
        }).then(function (features) {

            console.log(features);

            window.globals.segment.getSource().addFeatures(features[0][0].features);
        });
```

The error is thrown at the last line..I can see in the console statements that I am getting a feature collection returned.

EDIT: I drilled down into the returned features, and now I do not get an error, but I still do not get any segments rendered on the screen:

```
 console.log("features : " + (JSON.stringify(newfeatures[0][0])));
```

returns (what appears to be) a valid geoJSON

now I am trying

```
window.globals.segment.getSource().addFeatures(newfeatures[0][0]);
```

..no errors, but no segments rendered either

Bewlow is the response from the server, which appears to me to be valid geoJSON

(below is returned from

```
  console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response[0][0].features));

response: [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[1024345.25673969,182382.254051775],[1024608.61874577,182429.714914858]]]},"properties":{"f1":51278,"f2":"151 AVENUE"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[1024500.74855469,182994.720346525],[1024608.61874577,182429.714914858]]]},"properties":{"f1":51279,"f2":"80 STREET"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[1024608.61874577,182429.714914858],[1024715.1477322,181869.545103431]]]},"properties":{"f1":51281,"f2":"80 STREET"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[1024608.61874577,182429.714914858],[1024868.00470994,182478.149529263]]]},"properties":{"f1":51282,"f2":"151 AVENUE"}}]
```

I tried this as well, which does not throw an error, but does not result in the features being rendered either:

```
 window.globals.segment.getSource().getFeatures().push(newfeatures[0][0]);
```

EDIT 2:

I made a slight change to the scope of the empty aray in the save method, so now I am getting a FeatureCollection returned:

```
 {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[996193.689683363,207843.941317275],[996589.742040858,208151.906580597]]]},"properties":{"f1":35167,"f2":"COMMERCIAL STREET","segmentid":35167,"street":"COMMERCIAL STREET"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[996603.364060864,207892.573109776],[996589.742040858,208151.906580597]]]},"properties":{"f1":35172,"f2":"MANHATTAN AVENUE","segmentid":35172,"street":"MANHATTAN AVENUE"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[996603.364060864,207892.573109776],[997219.481595024,207967.464692265]]]},"properties":{"f1":35173,"f2":"BOX STREET","segmentid":35173,"street":"BOX STREET"}}]}
```

...this gives me a valid rendered layer in QGIS..but the features are still not rendered in my app.

Comment: How did you initialize your `segment` and `features` objects?

Comment: @Lars I edited my question to include more code.

Comment: does the console.log(features) logs valid geojson features ?

Comment: I had a similar issue recently and it had to do with needing to write GeoJSON with rightHanded: false. My guess is that there are some geometry issues with your respfeatures.features object.

Comment: @HichamZouarhi it looks valid yes, (see my edits above)

Comment: @the_skua I added 'rightHanded: false' to the geojson (see above) but I dont see any change

Comment: ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures does not use the rightHanded property. I think you're doing the right stuff on the client. To me, it seems like the issues is however you are requesting the GeoJSON features from the server.

Comment: have you tried ...getSource().getFeatures().push(features) ?

Comment: @the_skua I am not familiar with the righHanded properoty you mentioned... I added the response from the server above, it looks like valid geoJSON to me?

Comment: @HichamZouarhi I tried that suggestion, with same result - no error, but also no features rendered

Comment: @JasonBK I think you need to put format: new ol.format.GeoJSON() in between the curly braces of your new ol.source.Vector({ }) declaration.

Comment: You can check your geojson here: http://geojsonlint.com/  The String you posted is not valid. You have to use a `FeatureCollection`.

Comment: @the_skua I am not sure how to do that, can you add a comment with the formatting you suggest?

Comment: @JasonBK `window.globals.segment = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            }),
      visible: true,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#022835',
              width: 4
          })
      })
  });`

Comment: @Lars I f I delete the outermost brackets, then the geojson renders as expected in QGIS, but I am still getting a parse error in the site you posted

Comment: @the_skua I tried that, no effect (I think I had tried that earlier)..but see my edits above, I changed something in the save function, and now my geojson looks more like a Feature Collection

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with the fact that your geojson data should be more like this :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
 // and here go all your features
 ]
 }
```

while I don't have a good solution to solve it using OL3, you can try a work-around by handling it as a string and adding the GeoJSON header below with the `string1.concat(string2)` in javascript

or you could review your data retrieving code from the server

the ol.source.Vector() takes a Features, so I guess your geoJSON data should be as a FeatureCollection

Comment: I made an edit to my post, see above..after a slight change in my save function, i am now getting back a Feature Collection..but still no rendering..the geojson above looks to be the format you suggest, correct?

Comment: the crs is missing, see the second line of the example of the header in my answer, even though I'm not sure if it's what causing the problem but can you add it please ?

Comment: from what I can see, this is a valid geojson..I can try your suggestion, but lookg t these specs, what I have is fully valid..the coordinate system should be handled by Poj4 and the dataProjection/featureProjection proerties   http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html